# Validate EF-Core model with real database schema at startup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, orm, entity-framework-core

I use ASP.Net-Core with EF-Core.

My model class in code is configure wrong (typo in property name). This error will be detected at first access to database for this model.

Is there an option to force EF-Core validate each schema at startup from ASP.Net-Core? I do not mean the internal model validation. Instead I want that EF-Core validates the database.

Comment: It was not provided by default accroding to the document,but I think you could try Reverse Engineering for your requirement : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli